# Styling SVG charts to get sketch-like illustrations

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way that a web app generates some SVG graphs, with all regular lines and letters, and than, after a special css is applied, or maybe some special jQuery code is run, following is displayed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

So, just a limited number of SVG elements actually need special rendering: line, path, circle, and text - that's it.

Comment: apply css and make a funny cartoon strip?

Comment: See: http://dan.iel.fm/xkcd/

Comment: @Kerry Liu, that's it! The only thing missing is font, but that can be defined up-front. Please add the answer, and I will accept it. Many many thanks.

Comment: The source example uses the wrong link for the custom font, it should be: http://antiyawn.com/uploads/Humor-Sans-1.0.ttf

Comment: @Kerry Liu, even more beautiful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, Dan Foreman-Mackey has already [created a javascript library](http://dan.iel.fm/xkcd/) that helps create XKCD style graphs by using a custom line interpolation function in [D3](http://d3js.org/) to generate hand jitter. For more information also check out: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/10/07/xkcd-style-plots-in-matplotlib/

Note that the custom font link is incorrect in the source example and is available here: http://antiyawn.com/uploads/Humor-Sans-1.0.ttf

Comment: Best answer of all times!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is possible:

Google css+svg and you'll get some samples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/SVG_and_CSS

and others like:

http://www.sitepoint.com/svg-styling-with-css/

http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

**EDIT:**

I really didn't like the authors nonconstructive comment. anyway for the benefit of the others stackoverflow users and for my own curiosity, what can it be done:

[Manipulate the svg by using some javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/surviving-the-zombie-apocalypse-manipulating-svg-with-javascript/)

[Implement a freehand/cartoonished line manipulator](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=33)

[Manipulate the font of the svg text to some cartoon font](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/40-free-unique-cartoon-and-comic-fonts)

Manipulate the rest of the svg to change their colors (links above)